# Which database to use in my app?

Tags: java, android, database

I currently have a project at uni where I am creating an android application that is for an informal courier service where people can put jobs up and other users can bid on them. We are at the initial stages of development and are looking at the storage options and want something that will be able to be used across all instances of this application that are downloaded. I am wondering whether a cloud based database or SQLite is the best option. However get the impression from what I have read about SQLite that the databases created are local to that device rather than all devices on the app being able to access the same database and getting the same jobs that the couriers can 'bid on'.

Thanks, Oliver

Comment: Use a database hosted on a server somewhere that all devices can access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is like you said typically used for on-device storage. Alternative storage mechanisms that provide remote storage with local synchronization are the realm platform, firebase realtime database, and firestore. There are others, but those are the most common at this time.

It is also common to build your own back end / rest api / remote storage layer if you have the resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebase database service. What happens in that is when the data in the server changes, all the client also updates the data according to the server. If the device is offline, the data will be updated once it comes online.